# H2 Oracle Mode - Values of types "BOOLEAN" and "INTEGER" are not comparable

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, h2

I'm using Spring Boot and Hibernate and when running my tests in H2 (`2.1.210`)  I get an `Values of types "BOOLEAN" and "INTEGER" are not comparable` error. This is due to a `@Query` comparing a boolean to an integer. This works in Oracle correctly.

```
@Query("FROM TABLE_NAME t WHERE t.value= 0")
public List<Example> findExample();
```

`t.value` is of type `Boolean`.

I've found other questions with similar issues and the recommendation is to add this.

```
import org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect;

public class H2DialectExtended extends H2Dialect {

    @Override
    public String toBooleanValueString(boolean bool) {
        return bool ? "TRUE" : "FALSE";
    }
}
```

However this doesn't work.

How can I solve this?

H2/Hibernate Settings - `application.yml`

```
spring:

  driver:
    class-name: org.h2.Driver

  datasource:
    platform:
      url: jdbc:h2:mem:project_name;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MODE=Oracle;
      username: username
      password:

  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Comment: Oracle does not have a `BOOLEAN` data type in SQL. It does have a `BOOLEAN` data type in PL/SQL (but your query appears to be SQL and not PL/SQL).

Comment: The query works correctly in Oracle. It must map `t.value` to `0` or `1`. It just doesn't work in H2.

Comment: My point is that when you say "This is due to a @Query comparing a boolean to an integer." cannot be correct as Oracle does not have `BOOLEAN` data type in SQL so, inside the database, you are probably comparing an integer to an integer.

Comment: In my object `value` is of type `Boolean`. In the database it will be stored as `0` or `1` but Hibernate must be mapping it based on the dialect. I believe my statement is correct as I'm not saying Oracle has a boolean type. I'm saying that my code is essentially running `"TRUE" = 1` instead of mapping the values first. When executed in Oracle it runs `1 = 1` as expected. I've updated my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this `@Query("FROM TABLE_NAME t WHERE t.value= 0")` is exactly what you have, then it means that this is JPQL language, not SQL language. The way that you compare it, it is like the entity related with this has a integer field, which should not be the case. The Java field should have been `boolean`.

Then this should have been `@Query("FROM TABLE_NAME t WHERE t.value= false")` and it would be able to work both for Oracle and H2.

By default, when you use an ORM vendor like Hibernate and you have an Oracle database, the entity field `boolean value` will be matched in database level with type of Number(1) where `0 == false` and `1 == true` on ORM layer.

One way for this to work would be to have your entity field as the following:

```
@Type(type= "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")
private Boolean value;
```

Comment: This sounds like what I want although I'm having some trouble with it. If I use `t.value = false` I still get the same error. I've also tried setting the `@Type` for the variable. In the exception I can see it's converting the `false` to `0`. E.g `tableName.value=0`

Comment: @Michael do you get the same exception message with `@Type(type= "org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType")` ?

Comment: Yes the same message with @Type added. If I change it to `t.value = false` or `t.value = 0` it throws the same exception in both cases.

Comment: @Michael please share the properties that you use for test, in order to set h2 in Oracle mode

Comment: I've updated the question with the H2/Hibernate config.

Comment: @Michael try to use the property `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect`

Comment: Both H2Dialect and Oracle10gDialect throw the same exception. If I downgrade to H2 `1.4.200` it works for both dialects. Sounds like it's linked to this? https://groups.google.com/g/h2-database/c/AKjKqvGr9j8

Comment: @Michael you don't have to downgrade. You can have your current version and run it with `MODE=LEGACY` where as indicated `Unsafe comparison operators between numeric and boolean values are allowed.`  http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility. This does not seem to be the case for `MODE=Oracle` though :/

Comment: Yeah I should have mentioned it works fine in LEGACY mode however shouldn't it be possible in Oracle mode like this in the latest version?

Comment: I upgraded to Hibernate 5.6.5 and the changes you mentioned solved it! I didn't need the `@Type` annotations but changing `t.value=0` to `t.value=false` worked nicely.